# Python. Положить картинку в буфер обмена, reddit Selenuim WebDriver добавить в картинку из буфера обмена

Tags: python, windows, парсер, api, selenium

[image: Редактор редит]

[image: вставка картинки из буфера обмена]

Как скачать картинку имея url и занести в буфер обмена Windows, а как с помощью Selenium WebDriver из буфера обмена вставить картинку в движок reddit.com

[движок reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/submit)

Пример url:
"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/NEXT_Enfield_still_trading_during_the_Coronavirus_outbreak.jpg/170px-NEXT_Enfield_still_trading_during_the_Coronavirus_outbreak.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

Открываем вкладку LINK
[image]

Туда вставляем ссылку на картинку и вписываем тайтл

[image]

И жмём кнопочку POST

[image]

Код для селениума я так понимаю не особо нужен